# Let $F$ be a field, $f(x),g(x)\in F[x]$ and $f(x),g(x)\neq0.$ If there exist $a(x),b(x)\in F[x]$ such that $a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)=1$ prove $(f(x),g(x))=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Let $F$ be a field, $f(x),g(x)\in F[x]$ and $f(x),g(x) \neq 0 $. If there exist $a(x),b(x)\in F[x]$ such that $a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)=1$ prove $(f(x),g(x))=1$.

Let $d(x)=(f(x),g(x)) \Rightarrow d(x)|f(x)$ and $d(x)|g(x)\Rightarrow$

$d(x)|a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)=1 \Rightarrow d(x)=1$

So I have problem understanding the last step

$d(x) = 1$
does it have to do with the fact that $d(x)$ is gcd therefor it is monic?

Comment: I don't understand. The question in the header and the question is to prove $A\to B$ yet you are discussing $B\to A$. Can you edit this to make it clear what y ou are asking?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I am actually concerned about the B -> A I was able to understand the first part but at the reverse im struggling to understand the end. The above proof is from my textbook.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to reflect this reality!

Comment: If $d|1$ in $F[x]$ then $d$ is a unit, the only units in $F[x]$ are the constants, and the only monic unit is $1$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician oh it was that simple. Thank you very much! Edited my question aswell :P

Answer (score 1):

Since $d(x)$ divides both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, it divides any of their linear combinations.

Let $f(x)=d(x)F(x)$ and let $g(x)=d(x)G(x)$.

Then $a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)=a(x)d(x)F(x)+b(x)d(x)G(x)=d(x)[a(x)F(x)+b(x)G(x)].$

$d|1$, hence, $d=const.$

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "Let $F$ be a field, $f(x),g(x)∈F[x]$ and $f(x),g(x)≠0$. If there exist $a(x),b(x)∈F[x]$ such that $a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)=1$ prove $(f(x),g(x))=1$.

**Answer:** If by $(f(x),g(x))$ you mean the ideal in $F[x]$ generated by the polynomials $f(x),g(x)$ (this is standard notation for this ideal) the claim is immediate: By definition

$$(f(x),g(x)):=\{a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x):\text{ for all $a(x),b(x)\in F[x]$} \}$$

and if $af+bg=1$ it follows there is an equality of ideals $(f,g)=(1)$. The polynomials $f,g$ generate the unit ideal.